# C# 8 nullables and Result container

Tags: c#, generics, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a `IResult<T>` container that I use to handle errors. It looks like this:

```
public interface IResult<out T>
{
    ResultOutcome Outcome { get; }   //enum: {Failure, Uncertain, Success}
    string Description { get; }      //string describing the error, in case of !Success
    bool IsSuccess();                //Outcome == Success
    T Data { get; }                  //If success, it contains the data passed on, otherwise NULL
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
IResult<int> GetSomething()
{
    try{
        int result = //things that might throw...
        return Result<int>.Success(result);  
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        return Result<int>.Failure($"Something went wrong: {e.Message}");
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var result = GetSomething();
if (!result.IsSuccess()) return result; //<- error passed on.

int resultData = result.Data; //<- no errors, so there is something in here.
```

---

Until now, all good. When I introduce the nullable types, though, I have a problem:

```
public interface IResult<out T> where T : class // unfortunately this is necessary
{
    ...
    T? Data { get; }                  //If success, it contains the data passed on, otherwise NULL
}
```

```
var result = GetSomething();
if (!result.IsSuccess()) return result; //<- error passed on.

int resultData = result.Data; //<- WARNING!!! POSSIBLE DEREFERENCE OF NULL
```

---

**Now the question**: I am sure that `result.Data` contains something, as it passed the `IsSuccess()` step. How can I reassure the compiler about it? Is there a way or C#8 nullable concept is just not compatible with this?
Are there other ways to handle results in a similar fashion? (passing on containers instead of exceptions).

*P.s. 1*
Please, don't suggest to use `result.Data!;`.

*P.s. 2*
This code is already used on a thousand of lines or more, so if the change can be on the interface, rather than on the usages, it would be way better.

Comment: That's not possible. You should directly check Data against null

Comment: Any suggestion about alternative ways to encapsulate results on containers then?

Comment: The `Data` property presence depends on `IsSuccess` value, you can avoid it by null-forgiving operator, but get an exception at runtime. Why do you need `where T : class` constraint, if using `int` as typeparam below? Maybe just use `Nullable<T>` and check `HasValue`?

Comment: Thanks @PavelAnikhouski. The `int` was just as an example, I actually only use classes on my code. Using the `Nullable<T>` might actually be a good way of proceeding!

Comment: @AlvinSartor `Nullable<T>` [requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.8) `where : struct`. It cannot be used with classes because they are already nullable.

Comment: @AlvinSartor `Nullable<T>` is struct, its for value types only, therefore I was asking you about constraint

Comment: True that @GSerg. Not the right path then.

Comment: @AlvinSartor I do not see the problem you are describing. There is no warning on the line you are showing, because you are not using `.Data`, you are only storing it, for which it's safe for it to be `null`. If you later have `resultData.Something`, then that can generate a warning, which is correct.

Comment: @GSerg I'm storing or returning the `Data`, but this causes warnings (or errors in my case, I'm stricter than usual) as the return or the assigned types are non nullable.

Comment: @AlvinSartor `var resultData = result.Data` will not cause a warning because it's a `var` and it resolves to `T?`. If you actually have `already_declared_varibale = result.Data`, that's different, but then you are not showing the code you are actually running.

Comment: Fair enough @GSerg, I might have oversimplified the code. I corrected it.

Comment: So effectively you want the [`[NotNullWhen]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute?view=netcore-3.1) attribute, but for properties. There isn't one I'm afraid. You could have `bool GetData<T>(IResult<T> r, [NotNullWhen(true)] out T? value){ value = r.Data; return r.Success; }`, but then you'd have to use that to access `.Data` in all places.

Comment: What's wrong with using the `!` for assuring the compiler that it's not `null`? It is exactly why this operator exists, to assure the compiler that you are 100% sure that this value will never be null (at least in that case). However you can use the `??` to retun a default value, for example: `int resultData = result.Data ?? 0;`. This expression returns 0 if the `result.Data` is null, and the `result.Data` otherwise.

Comment: @KoppaPéter to me, using `!` is a bit like cheating. It introduces human factor and allows us not to listen to the compiler (maybe the next person will just put it there copying my code, while it wasn't supposed to). Well written code should exploit the compiler, not go against it.

Comment: @GSerg it is not the cleanest way to do it, but it is definitely the best I've seen until now.

Comment: @AlvinSartor I suspect the real problem is caused by the way `Result` is implemented. The `Result` pattern uses two different *types*, one for good and one for bad results. Bad results need no Data and hence, no need for nullable data. No need for `out` either

Comment: @AlvinSartor besides, IResult and the other functional patterns like Option/Maybe are used to avoid nulls. If you want to return *optional* data in a Result, create an `Option<T>` class/struct.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Option<T>` wouldn't work, I need to propagate a message about what went wrong and the data is *null* only in case of failure. Implementing 2 (or 3, in my case) subtypes might be a good strategy though. Even though it would mean rewriting completely all (and I mean all!!) my code, so it is not doable now.

Comment: @AlvinSartor that's why `Result` doesn't use only one type, in fact, why it was created in the first place. You can use default implementation members to migrate from your current API to the new one. Eventually, you'll have to, especially once C# 9 adds full support through discriminated unions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

If you *did* change the usage, and converted `IsSuccess` to a property, you could get rid of nullability issues *and* get exhaustive matching. This switch expression, is exhaustive ie the compiler can check that all possibilities have been met. It does require that each branch only retrieves a valid property though  :

```
var message=result switch { {IsSuccess:true,Data:var data} => $"Got some: {data}",
                            {IsSuccess:false,Description:var error} => $"Oops {error}",
             };
```

If your methods accept and return `IResult<T>` objects, you could write something like :

```
IResult<string> Doubler(IResult<string> input)
{
    return input switch { {IsSuccess:true,Data:var data} => new Ok<string>(data+ "2"),
                          {IsSuccess:false} => input
    };  
}

...

var result2=new Ok<string>("3");
var message2=Doubler(result2) switch { 
                     {IsSuccess:true,Data:var data} => $"Got some: {data}",
                     {IsSuccess:false,Description:var error} => $"Oops {error}",
             };
```

---

**Original Answer**

It looks like the *real* problem is the implementation of the [Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results) pattern. This pattern has two characteristics :

- It prevents the use of invalid result values at the type level. It does this by It uses two different types to represent good and bad results. By doing so, each type only carries what it needs.
- It forces the clients to handle all cases or explicitly ignore them.

Some languages like Rust have a built-in type for this. Functional languages that support option types/discriminated unions like F#, can easily implement it with just :

```
type Result<'T,'TError> =
    | Ok of ResultValue:'T
    | Error of ErrorValue:'TError
```

Exhaustive pattern matching means clients have to handle both cases. That type is so common though, it made it into the language itself.

**C# 8**

In C# 8 we can implement the two types, without the exhaustive pattern matching. For now, the types need a common class, either an interface or abstract class, which doesn't really need to have any members. There are many ways to implement them, eg :

```
public interface IResult<TSuccess,TError>{}

public class Ok<TSuccess,TError>:IResult<TSuccess,TError>
{
    public TSuccess Data{get;}

    public Ok(TSuccess data)=>Data=data;

    public void Deconstruct(out TSuccess data)=>data=Data;
}

public class Fail<TSuccess,TError>:IResult<TSuccess,TError>
{
    public TError Error{get;}

    public Fail(TError error)=>Error=error;

    public void Deconstruct(out TError error)=>error=Error;
}
```

We could use structs instead of classes.

Or, to use a syntax closer to C# 9's discriminated unions, the classes can be nested. The type can still be an interface, but I really don't like writing `new IResult<string,string>.Fail` or naming an interface `Result` instead of `IResult` :

```
public abstract class Result<TSuccess,TError>
{
    public class Ok:Result<TSuccess,TError>
    {
        public TSuccess Data{get;}
        public Ok(TSuccess data)=>Data=data;
        public void Deconstruct(out TSuccess data)=>data=Data;
    }

    public class Fail:Result<TSuccess,TError>
    {
       public TError Error{get;}
        public Fail(TError error)=>Error=error;
        public void Deconstruct(out TError error)=>error=Error;
    }

    //Convenience methods
    public static Result<TSuccess,TError> Good(TSuccess data)=>new  Ok(data);
    public static Result<TSuccess,TError> Bad(TError error)=>new  Fail(error);
}
```

We can use pattern matching to handle `Result` values. Unfortunatelly, C# 8 doesn't offer exhaustive matching so we need to add a default case too.

```
var result=Result<string,string>.Bad("moo");
var message=result switch { Result<string,string>.Ok (var Data) => $"Got some: {Data}",
                            Result<string,string>.Fail (var Error) => $"Oops {Error}"
                            _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected result case")
                      };
```

**C# 9**

C# 9 is (probably) going to add discriminated unions through [enum classes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/discriminated-unions.md). We'll be able to write :

```
enum class Result
{
    Ok(MySuccess Data),
    Fail(MyError Error)
}
```

and use it through pattern matching. This syntax already works in C# 8 as long as there's a matching deconstructor. C# 9 will add exhaustive matching and probably simplify the syntax too  :

```
var message=result switch { Result.Ok (var Data) => $"Got some: {Data}",
                            Result.Fail (var Error) => $"Oops {Error}"
                          };
```

**Updating the existing type through DIMs**

Some of the existing functions like `IsSuccess` and `Outcome` are just convenience methods. In fact, F#'s option types also expose the "kind" of the value as a *tag* . We can add such methods to the interface and return a fixed value from the implementations :

```
public interface IResult<TSuccess,TError>
{
    public bool IsSuccess {get;}
    public bool IsFailure {get;}
    public bool ResultOutcome {get;}
}

public class Ok<TSuccess,string>:IResult<TSuccess,TError>
{
    public bool IsSuccess     =>true;
    public bool IsFailure     =>false;
    public bool ResultOutcome =>ResultOutcome.Success;
    ...
}
```

The `Description` and `Data` properties can be implemented too, as a stop gap measure - they break the Result pattern and pattern matching makes them obsolete anyway :

```
public class Ok<TSuccess,TError>:IResult<TSuccess,TError>
{
    ...
    public TError Description=>throw new InvalidOperationException("A Success Result has no Description");
    ...
}
```

Default interface members can be used to avoid littering the concrete types :

```
public interface IResult<TSuccess,TError>
{
    //Migration methods
    public TSuccess Data=>
        (this is Ok<TSuccess,TError> (var Data))
        ?Data
        :throw new InvalidOperationException("An Error has no data");

    public TError Description=> 
        (this is Fail<TSuccess,TError> (var Error))
        ?Error
        :throw new InvalidOperationException("A Success Result has no Description");

    //Convenience methods
    public static IResult<TSuccess,TError> Good(TSuccess data)=>new  Ok<TSuccess,TError>(data);
    public static IResult<TSuccess,TError> Bad(TError error)=>new  Fail<TSuccess,TError>(error);

}
```

**Modifications to add exhaustive matching**

We could avoid the default cases in the pattern matching exceptions if we use only *one* flag and the migration properties :

```
public interface IResult<TSuccess,TError>
{
    public bool IsSuccess{get;}
    public bool IsFailure=>!IsSuccess;
    //Migration methods
    ...
}

var message2=result switch { {IsSuccess:true,Data:var data} => $"Got some: {data}",
                             {IsSuccess:false,Description:var error} => $"Oops {error}",
             };
```

This time, the compiler detects there are only two cases, and both are covered. The migration properties allow the compiler to retrieve the correct type. The consuming code has to change *and* use the correct pattern, but I suspect it already worked that

Comment: Nice overlook on C#9, I discovered some stuff I didn't know.

Comment: @AlvinSartor I added how you can use the existing interface with the common Result pattern.

Comment: @AlvinSartor as for the actual implementation, ie nested classes or not, interface vs abstract class, it's not clear which is better. A strong consideration is minimizing changes when C# 9 comes out which probably means nested types. The syntax could still change though

Comment: Thank you, it is a very complete answer! Even though throwing an exception seems a bit counter-intuitive (as the whole `IResult` is there to avoid them) it is definitely the best way to handle it so far!

Comment: @AlvinSartor what would you do if someone tried to read `Data` from an `Error`? That's clearly an erroneous state. That's why it's wrong putting `Description` and `Data` on the interface. As for `_ => throw ...` in the switch expressions, it's because C# 8 doesn't know whether the expression covered every type - there could be *another* type derived from `Result`.

Comment: @AlvinSartor I added how you could get rid of nullability and exhaustiveness issues by changing the client code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there a way using the above to deal with an error result (in an `if`) and then continue with the Data (`TSuccess`) without creating a second scope for it ?

Comment: @kofifus what do you mean? There are no scopes involved and the Result idiom already handles errors. If you want the TError part to contain data, you can easily do so. If you want to use more than two types in the discriminated union, you can also do that. The idiom already works with pattern matching in `if` and `switch` to extract the payload or error

Comment: What I mean is to deal with the error inside ie an if scope: 'if (F() is { OK: false, Error: var error }) {  Console.WriteLine(error);  return; }' and then to have access to data for the rest of the function without being inside another if scope etc. Similar to how you would do it if in the traditional error handling way where your function returns an error boolean/flag

Answer (score 6):

With c# 9 there is `MemberNotNullWhen` attribute which can hide corresponding warning when `IsSuccess` is checked

```cs
public interface IResult<out T>
{
    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Data))]
    bool IsSuccess();
    T? Data { get; }
}

IResult<string> res = GetSomeResult();
if(!res.IsSuccess())
   throw new Exception(); // or just return something else

var len = res.Data.Length; // no nullability warning
```

The official [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) are not updated yet.
I received more nullability information about it within [this](https://youtu.be/SrkfMtm3EFQ) lection.
In order to use the above attribute, you must use .net50, or set language version within csproj file as c#9. Another way to backport these attributes is to use [Nullable package](https://github.com/manuelroemer/Nullable).

Comment: This doesn't work; the `MemberNotNullWhenAttribute` is limited to constructors. Client code will still have to null-check the Data property when Nullable Reference Types are enabled and the type is `T?`.

Comment: I am using almost the same code in production. The idea is that if specific function/property is checked you can indicate that other property is null/not-null. The problem with interface definition of `MemberNotNullWhenAttribute` is implementation won't inherit the attribute. You will need to use interface when defining it in the code (i.e. IResult<string> res = GetSomeResult()), or define the attribute at class level. 
Take a look at my example, hope it does help.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/5onNlL

Comment: You're right; it was actually a bug in ReSharper that made me think it doesn't work. ReSharper doesn't have full support for MemberNotNull yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the C# 8.0 part of the above (great!) @PanagiotisKanavos answer in one piece:

```
using System;

#nullable enable

namespace ErrorHandling {
  public interface IResult<TSuccess, TError> {
    public bool OK { get; }

    public TSuccess Data => (this is Ok<TSuccess, TError>(var Data)) ? Data : throw new InvalidOperationException("An Error has no data");
    public TError Error => (this is Fail<TSuccess, TError>(var Error)) ? Error : throw new InvalidOperationException("A Success Result has no Description");

    public static IResult<TSuccess, TError> Good(TSuccess data) => new Ok<TSuccess, TError>(data);
    public static IResult<TSuccess, TError> Bad(TError error) => new Fail<TSuccess, TError>(error);
  }

  public class Ok<TSuccess, TError> : IResult<TSuccess, TError> {
    public bool OK => true;
    public TSuccess Data { get; }

    public Ok(TSuccess data) => Data = data;
    public void Deconstruct(out TSuccess data) => data = Data;
  }

  public class Fail<TSuccess, TError> : IResult<TSuccess, TError> {
    public bool OK => false;
    public TError Error { get; }

    public Fail(TError error) => Error = error;
    public void Deconstruct(out TError error) => error = Error;
  }

  class Main {
    public IResult<int, string> F() {
      if (DateTime.Now.Year < 2020) return IResult<int, string>.Good(3);
      return IResult<int, string>.Bad("error");
    }

    public void F1() {
      var message = F() switch { 
        { OK: true, Data: var data } => $"Got some: {data}",
        { OK: false, Error: var error } => $"Oops {error}",
      };
      Console.WriteLine(message);
    }


    public void F2() {
      if (F() is { OK: false, Error: var error }) {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
        return;
      }

      if (F() is { OK: true, Data: var data }) { // Is there a way to get data without a new scope ?
        Console.WriteLine(data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```